# When handling RabbitMQ queue events can CompleteableFuture be used for void and not void calls?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, completable-future

Our application uses restEndpoints to queue objects to RabbitMQ which are then picked up by RabbitMQ Listeners with the following signatures with approximately 50-ish different events:

```
@RabbitHandler
public void handle(DocumentUpdated event){
    //code that records the update event
}

@RabbitHandler
public List<Subscriber> handle(DocumentDeleted event){
    //code that saves the deleted state and then 
    //finds the subscribers to notify of the deletion and returns List<Subscriber>

    return subscribers
}
```

Currently on the void returns it appears rabbit is waiting for the method block to finish before responding.  I have been tasked to convert listeners to best economically use threading.

After researching multiple articles it seems that CompleteableFuture would handle both conditions as follows:

```
private Executor handleExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
private DocumentService service //Autowired by Lombok

//member args and a ctor

@RabbitHandler
public void handle(DocumentUpdated event){
    CompleteableFuture.runAsynch(() -> service.documentUpdated(event), handleExecutor)
        .exceptionally(ex -> //log the exception)
}

@RabbitHandler
public List<Subscriber> handle(DocumentDeleted event){
    //service.documentDeleted returns List<Subscriber>
    List<Subscriber> subscribers = CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsynch(()->service.documentDeleted(event), handleExecutor)
        .exceptionally(ex -> //log the exception and return emptyList)
        .get()

    return subscribers
}
```

Forgive me for any typos, I have to dev on an isolated dev environment and cannot cut/paste.  My questions regarding the above refactor of the listener are:

1. Is the runAsynch the right approach for void methods or is there a better option?
2. Is the supplyAsynch the right approach for returned values or is there a better option?
3. Am I understanding how to use .exceptionally correctly?
4. Is there a better way besides CompletableFuture to handle this situation?

Please accept my sincere gratitude in advance for confirmation or editing of my refactor approach.